# How to use RSUNICODE codes?

Tags: input-methods

I would like to know, on an Android smartphone or PC, how do I use the RSUNICODE floating point number to enter a character, and why would I use a RSUNICODE number to enter text in this way? Is this what RSUNICIDE codes are used for... to enter text?

Thanks..

Answer (score 2):

as far as i know, the function of rsunicode is to find out the **radical & stroke count** from an input, the output is the radical index (1-214) & number of strokes, excluding the radical of the character.

**it's not for inputting text.**